# How to change the borderbrush on a Mouse Over event in WPF

Tags: wpf

I am trying to change the color of the `BorderBrush` when the mouse is hovering over the button. I have created a new control template for the button however when setting up the triggers visual studio tells me i have got to use an `EventTrigger` but when i use this there is no `MouseOver` event, only a `MouseEnter` event. When applying this and running the solution the border brush does not change. Any Suggestions?

EDIT:

Code I am having the issue with:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="LogInButton">
            <Grid Width="AUTO" Height="AUTO">
                <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder"
                                    BorderBrush="#B7B7B7"
                                    BorderThickness="2"
                                    Background="Transparent"
                                    Cursor="Hand">

                    <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>


                    <Border.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseMove">
                            <EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ButtonBorder"
                                                            Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush"
                                                            To="White"
                                                            Duration="0"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Border.Triggers>


                </Border>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Grid.Resources>

    <Button Template="{StaticResource LogInButton}" Tag="Images/Login.png" Height="50" Width="50" Background="Transparent">
    </Button>

</Grid>
```

Comment: What about `MouseMove` event?

Comment: You could use a local `Style` which allows `Trigger`s and use the `IsMouseOver` Property to set the `BorderBrush`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just add a `Trigger` to `<ControlTemplate.Triggers>` instead of adding an `EventTrigger` to `<Border.Triggers>`:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="LogInButton">
    <Grid Width="AUTO" Height="AUTO">
        <Border x:Name="ButtonBorder"
                BorderBrush="#B7B7B7"
                BorderThickness="2"
                Background="Transparent"
                Cursor="Hand">
            <Image Source="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"/>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="ButtonBorder" Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```